# SQL Server 2008 installation fail by performance counter issue?

Tags: sql-server, windows-xp

I am installing SQL Server 2008 on Windows XP. In the first step to check system configuration, I met with a strange error like this,

> performance counter registry
>   configuration item consistency
>   checking failed.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to have been asked and answered here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1163078.aspx